# I want to get incomming call number and compare it

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, gsm

Hello i want to get and compare incomming call number, it works but not as I want.
When im calling from good number it print that I was calling form saved number when the number is stop calling i need to do it on start. And `else` is printing when nobody is calling. How can i do it? Here is my code:

```
String d = "";
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial1.println("AT");
  delay(500);
  Serial1.println("AT+CLIP=1");
  delay(1000);
  Serial1.println("AT+CPIN=1439");
}
void loop()
{ 
 d = Serial1.readString();
 if(d.indexOf("xxxxxxxxx") >=0)
   {
 Serial.println("call is from saved number");
    } else {
       Serial.println("call is not from saved number");
      }
}
```

Comment: Hint#1: "readString()" has a timeout. What should your code do then? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadString

Comment: @MikaelPatel When it's recognised number I will be sending HTTP POST to my api.

Comment: You need to check that a string has received and not returned due to a timeout. It is only when a string with a number, a call, has been received that the valid phone number should be checked. Please fix the control logic of your sketch.

Comment: Could you help me with it? I'm new in C but I need it to build my system to mobile app

Comment: You could for instance add "if (d.length() == 0) return;" after "d = Serial1.readString();".

Comment: Should I add it below my `if` statements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino Serial class member function [`readString()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadString) has a builtin timeout. The function will return on timeout. The default timeout period is 1000 ms. The timeout can be set with [`setTimeout()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/SetTimeout).

The sketch needs to filter out empty lines (timeout). This can be done by adding a check of the string length. See below for an example of checking:

```
void loop()
{ 
  String d = Serial1.readString(); 
  if (d.length() == 0) return;
  Serial.print(d);
  if (d.indexOf("xxxxxxxxx") >= 0) {
    Serial.println(": call is from saved number");
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println(": call is not from saved number");
  }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Try the above and check the output to the serial monitor.

Comment: I have tried but the biggest problem is that serial print print call is from saved number after I decline calling

Comment: Please add an example of the output to the serial monitor. That would help understand the issue.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PKHDP84

Comment: Might want to use `readStringUntil()` if you want to capture per line and not until timeout. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil

Comment: String d = Serial1.readStringUntil();  I got the following error : `no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::readStringUntil()'`

Comment: You need to give a terminator character. For instance '\r', please read the documentation page.

Comment: I will try it as soon as it will be possible. If it works I will give your answer "the best"